# エスケープシーケンスの出力を確認する方法

Tags: swift3

```
var string2 = String()
string2 += "\"Swift\"\n\tNew language" //改行コードとタブを挿入
```

改行とタブがうまく反映されません。なぜでしょうか？

---

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

返答いただき、ありがとうございます。
確認画面は横の灰色部分より確認しておりました。あそこにプログラムのアウトプットが反映されるものばかりと考えているのですが、
添付の写真通り、ログ画面より反映されているのが正しい確認の仕方でしょうか？
だとしたら、どのようにして確認すればいいのか教えていただけますか？
　今現在frame #がたくさん書かれています。。。

Answer (score 2):

> 確認画面は横の灰色部分より確認しておりました。あそこにプログラムのアウトプットが反映されるものばかりと考えているのですが、

「確認画面」というか、変数の値を調べる方法は、Playgroundでは3とおり用意しています。常時表示しているのは、「横の灰色部分」です。ふたつ目はクイックルックで、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上のスクリーンショットの、目の形をしたアイコンをクリックすると、表示されます。
3つ目はResultと呼ぶもので、上のスクリーンショットの、矢印の先のアイコンをクリックすると、エディタ内に、インラインで表示されます。（下図）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

対象が数値をメンバーとする配列だと、グラフで表示されるなど、じつは、これがいちばんPlaygroundらしい部分です。活用しない手はありません。

Answer (score 1):

はじめまして。改行とタブが反映されないのは何で確認されたのでしょうか？

Xcode 8.2.1のplaygroundで確認しましたが、添付画面下部のログ（`print`文で出力したもの）では正しく改行もタブ挿入も行われているようです。
string2を表示する系がタブ、改行をサポートしていないもので確認をし、有効で無いと思われている可能性が高いです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

質問が更新されたので補足です。
画面の下のログ画面は、名前の通り実行ログが表示されます。
そちらでエラーが出る理由はわかりませんが、ログ画面に変数の内容を
出力するためには`print`文が必要です。

コード編集画面右側にも変数の値のモニター用に内容が表示されますが
そちらは正規表現エスケープを展開しない形での表示になるのだと思います。
`\n`や`\t`等のエスケープ表現を約束事にしたがって展開するのは
表示系なので、テキストをそのまま表示するだけの右側の灰色のモニター部分
では、どういう文字列が格納されているのか？を表示するためにエスケープ表現を
展開しない形で表示しているのだと思います。

Comment: コメントいただき、ありがとうございました。